# How does repeated cross validation go about 'averaging' model coefficients?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, caret, elastic-net

No matter how much I google, I cannot find the answer to this simple question.

Say you do 10-fold, repeated (5x) CV logistic regression with elastic net regularization.

For alpha you try `seq(0,1,length=10)`, and for lambda you try  `seq(0.1, 0.5, length = 5)`

It tries lots of combinations of alpha and lambda to find the best combination, and the corresponding model coefficients. My question is: how does the "repeated 5x" part come into play? Each repeat has its own coefficient estimates. So did it just literally average the 5 to give you final "best model"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated 5x means you do the cross validation process 5 times. With one CV, you split the data into 10 parts, train on 9 parts test on 1 part. This is based on 1 partitioning of the data. You can now resample your data and partition again into a different 10 parts. This is the "repeated".

To answer your question is

> how does the "repeated 5x" part come into play? Each repeat has its
>   own coefficient estimates. So did it just literally average the 5 to
>   give you final "best model"?

Instead of having 10 datapoints to estimate the metric (for example accuracy), you now have 5x10 datapoints because you repeated the CV 5 times. It calculates the mean accuracy across these 50 data points for each combination and chooses, the combination with the best metric, for example, highest accuracy.

We can do an example:

```
library(caret)
data = iris
data$Species = factor(ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor",1,0))

mdl1 = train(Species ~ .,data=data,method="glmnet",
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=10),tuneLength=3)

 mdl1$resample
    Accuracy     Kappa Resample
1  0.7333333 0.3333333   Fold08
2  0.6000000 0.0000000   Fold04
3  0.7333333 0.4000000   Fold07
4  0.6666667 0.2857143   Fold10
5  0.6000000 0.1000000   Fold03
6  0.7333333 0.3333333   Fold06
7  0.6666667 0.1176471   Fold09
8  0.8000000 0.4705882   Fold01
9  0.8000000 0.5263158   Fold02
10 0.9333333 0.8421053   Fold05
```

The above shows you the accuracy across each fold, for the final model. We can calculate the average and you can see it corresponds to the final result:

```
mean(mdl1$resample$Accuracy)
[1] 0.7266667

mdl
glmnet 

150 samples
  4 predictor
  2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  alpha  lambda        Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.10   0.0004409547  0.7293333  0.3464136
  0.10   0.0044095469  0.7293333  0.3483365
  0.10   0.0440954694  0.7080000  0.2604608
  0.55   0.0004409547  0.7280000  0.3443084
  0.55   0.0044095469  0.7280000  0.3463114
  0.55   0.0440954694  0.7133333  0.2674701
  1.00   0.0004409547  0.7266667  0.3426221
  1.00   0.0044095469  0.7266667  0.3441009
  1.00   0.0440954694  0.7173333  0.2750243
```

Now we do repeated, you can see that the data has now 50 entries,compared to 10 previously:

```
mdl2 = train(Species ~ .,data=data,method="glmnet",
trControl=trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number=10,repeats=5),tuneLength=3)

head(mdl2$resample)
   Accuracy     Kappa    Resample
1 0.8666667 0.6666667 Fold04.Rep5
2 0.8666667 0.6666667 Fold05.Rep5
3 0.7333333 0.4000000 Fold01.Rep4
4 0.8000000 0.5263158 Fold02.Rep4
5 0.6666667 0.2105263 Fold02.Rep5
6 0.7333333 0.4000000 Fold09.Rep2

dim(mdl2$resample)
[1] 50  3

mean(mdl2$resample$Accuracy)
[1] 0.7306667

mdl2
glmnet 

150 samples
  4 predictor
  2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  alpha  lambda        Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.10   0.0004409547  0.7226667  0.3428366
  0.10   0.0044095469  0.7306667  0.3564700
  0.10   0.0440954694  0.7146667  0.2772609
  0.55   0.0004409547  0.7213333  0.3402191
  0.55   0.0044095469  0.7280000  0.3505853
  0.55   0.0440954694  0.7120000  0.2589946
  1.00   0.0004409547  0.7213333  0.3402191
  1.00   0.0044095469  0.7293333  0.3530414
  1.00   0.0440954694  0.7146667  0.2639771

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 0.1 and lambda = 0.004409547.
```

Comment: i know this might get deleted since the comment isn't furthering the discussion but just wanted to say thank you so much for this. Really helpful with the example that I can plug in myself too!

Comment: hey @StatsNTats, you're welcome :) Thanks for letting me know its useful

Answer (score 1):

The cross-validation is to select a model. Aggregation makes the new estimator which has to be tested again and makes the previous cross-validation not much meaningful.

If you think aggregation will make the better model, you may do bagging but the bagged estimator has to be cross-validated.

The cross-validation doesn't give out the final model as it uses only the part of the training sample to train its model. If you use one of the models from the cross-validation process, it would have a bigger variance than the variance of a model constructed using the whole training set.

After you assess your model building process through cross-validation, you need to build the final model using the whole data.

About the hyper-parameter for the final model, there are several ways to choose. One way is to get the hyper-parameter from the best model of the cross-validation process. The other method is to choose the final hyper-parameter by testing on the final validation set.